# How do you compare integer values in two separate lists?

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing, compare

This is my current code:

```
predict_results = []

with open ("newTesting.predict") as inputfile:

    for line in inputfile:
        predict_results.append(line.strip())
print predict_results


first_list = []

with open ("newTesting") as inputfile:

    for line in inputfile:
        first_list.append(line.strip().split()[0])
print first_list


if predict_results [0] == first_list[0]:

    print True
else:
    print False
```

This is my current output:

['-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1']
['1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1']

False

I can only check index [0] which is correct. How do I check all indexes in predict_results with first_list

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
>>> from pandas import *

>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = [2,2,3]

>>> S1 = Series(L1)
>>> S2 = Series(L2)

>>> RES = S1==S2

>>> RES
0    False
1     True
2     True
```

For your case:

```
>>> S1 = Series(predict_results)
>>> S2 = Series(first_list)

>>> RES = S1==S2

>>> RES[0]   # check   predict_results[0]==first_list[0]
>>> RES[1]   # check   predict_results[1]==first_list[1]
```

And you can use loop:

```
for x,y in zip(predict_results,first_list):
    if(x==y):
        print False
    else:
        print True
```